# WM_CHAR doesn't work with notepad.exe

Tags: c, winapi, sendmessage

I use Windows 7 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I use this code to insert digit chars to the window of calc.exe:

```
STARTUPINFO         si  = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi  = { 0 };

memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

si.cb = sizeof(si);

BOOL bResult = CreateProcess("c:\\windows\\syswow64\\calc.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
HWND hWnd = FindWindow("CalcFrame", NULL);

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'1', 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'2', 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'3', 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'4', 0);
```

This code works perfect. And when I replace `"c:\\windows\\syswow64\\calc.exe"` with `"c:\\windows\\syswow64\\notepad.exe"` and `"CalcFrame"` with `"Notepad"` it doesn't insert chars into the Notepad window.

Comment: You are sending the messages to the main window. But why did you reject UI automation?

Comment: In the `calc.exe` I  am also sending messages to main window. UI automation is for .NET applications, isn't it?

Comment: No it is not UI automation is the way to do this

Comment: I know. I just need to send messages to other process' window.

Comment: UI Automation is available for both .net and native applications. It's geared toward .net, yes, but native applications can use it; [here's the documentation entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: No. That's not what you are trying to do. You did not set out with the goal of sending messages. You want to automate another program.

Comment: Furthermore, to clear up your confusion, it's very likely that the `calc.exe` main window class handles `WM_CHAR` to allow entering numbers or operations without having focus on the buttons; you can do this too. Notepad does not because its client area is just an `EDIT` control. You still shouldn't generate input directly like this if you want to talk to another program, though. It may seem to work, but then things will break badly, as you see with Notepad. Here's [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx) listing other things that can go wrng.

Comment: But why sending messages to calc.exe succeeds but sending messages to notepad.exe fails? `SendMessage()` does not fail, but no characters appear in Notepad.

Comment: Well, I told you why in the first comment. You are sending the messages to the main window.

Comment: @andlabs What can I do to send messages to other application except hooking? Or only hooking is acceptable?

Comment: Why are you obsessed with sending messages? And why do you want to hook? Why did you decide that automation was not an acceptable solution to a need to automate? Since you clearly are new to this, why don't you consider listening to advice?

Comment: OK, how can I obtain hWnd of current active window (sub-window of notepad.exe which is not active really, because notepad.exe window in my situation is not active.

Comment: @David Heffernan I must use only native code.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do, in the end, after doing all this practicing? Because at this point I assume you're just practicing what you *can* do rather than (or perhaps before) trying to accomplish a specific goal.

Comment: Feel free to automate with native code.

Comment: The URL I showed you earlier is a native code API to UI Automation. I'm guessing you're confused because it's a COM interface and is thus object-oriented (and Microsoft's docs use C++ syntax for it); that doesn't make it any less native than native, though, and COM != .net (even though they can be used together).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a child window of class `EDIT` inside the client area of Notepad's main window.  For what you are doing, you need to locate and send messages to *that* window rather than Notepad's main window.

```
BOOL bResult = CreateProcess("c:\\windows\\syswow64\\notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
HWND hWnd = FindWindow("Notepad", NULL);
hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, "EDIT", NULL); // <-- add this

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'1', 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'2', 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'3', 0);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)'4', 0);
```

Use Spy++ to explore window hierarchy and find these things.

Comment: For that matter, there may be multiple instances of `Notepad` running at a time, but `FindWindow()` returns the first matching HWND, which may be the wrong HWND. To find the *correct* HWND that belongs to the process being spawned, use `EnumWindows()` instead of `FindWindow()`, where the enumeration callback uses `GetClassName()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to filter for a `Notepad` window that belongs to the Process ID that `CreateProcess()` returns. The enumeration can then return to the calling code the single HWND that matches those criteria.

Comment: I know it, now I am testing with single Notepad and that's why I decided to use `EnumWindows()` later - `FindWindow()` is only for testing.

But I have another question: is there a method to determine which subwindow of top-level window has focus now? For example, I want to send messages not to the Notepad but to window with two Edits, and I need to send chars to currently focused Edit.

Comment: Tried to get ID of Notepad's window thread with `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` - it works. Tried to attach input to my thread with `AttachThreadInput()` - it works. But when I try to get hWnd of currently focused window with `GetFocus()` - it returns NULL. Why?

Comment: `GetGUIThreadInfo()` returns `TRUE`, but `GUITHREADINFO` stucture is filled with zeroes (except `cbSize`). What am I doing wrong?